# Scanset Conversion not producing correct results?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm working on a program that needs to read from a file with data seperated by commas. Ex: Name,Name. I'm debugging and can't solve it. The below code is just what I'm using to test right now.

`fscanf(input, "%50[a-zA-Z], %50[a-zA-Z], %d, %d, %d, %10[a-zA-Z], %15[a-zA-Z]", newNode->lastName, newNode->firstName, &newNode->birthDay.month, &newNode->birthDay.day, &newNode->birthDay.year, newNode->major, newNode->classStand);`

leaves newNode completly empty, while

`fscanf(input, "%50[a-zA-Z], %50[a-zA-Z], %d, %d, %d, %10[a-zA-Z], %15[a-zA-Z]", newNode->last, newNode->first, &newNode->birthDay.month, &newNode->birthDay.day, &newNode->birthDay.year, newNode->major, newNode->class);`

on my test file works perfectly fine.

I've even gone as far as making a second file with very similar code to my actual project and it works perfectly fine. Also on the broken file, if i simply use "%s" instead of trying the scanset conversion, it records the entire line as expected.
Sample input:

Doe,John,1,23,2000,CS-BS,Junior

Bar,Foo,4,56,2000,CS-BS,Junior

Heres all the files.Pardon the mess, i haven't gotten to the tidying up part yet

functions.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct bDayType {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
} bDay;

typedef struct linkList {
    char lastName[50];
    char firstName[50];
    char major[10];
    char classStand[15];

    bDay birthDay;

    struct linkList *next;
} node_t;


/*Parameters: input - input file containing all student info 
 *            head - the head of the linked list
 *Return: node_t* - a pointer to the list
 *This function will recieve info from the input file and fill out 
the linked list using
 *the "add" function
 */
node_t* createList(FILE* input, node_t** head);

/*Parameters: node - node to be added to the list 
 *                head - the head of the linked list
 *Adds a node to the end of the linked list
 *
 */
void add(node_t** node, node_t** head);

/*Parameters: input - the input file
 *Return: node_t* - a pointer to the newly populated node
 *Reads data from input and fills out nodes with the data.
 *
 */
node_t* readNodeInfo(FILE* input);

/*Parameters: output - the file being written to
 *                head - the head of the linked list
 *Prints the data to the output file, then sends a messgage to the 
terminal when done 
 *
 */
void printList(FILE* output, node_t* head);

/*Parameters: output - the file being written to
 *
 *Prints 80 asterisks to the output file to seperate data entries
 *
 */
void printBorder(FILE* output);

/*Parameters: head - the head of the linked list
 *
 *Deletes all nodes from the list to free memory
 *
 */
void deleteList(node_t** head);

#endif
```

functions.c

```
    #include "functions.h"

    node_t* createList(FILE* input, node_t** head) {
        while (!feof(input)) {
            node_t* newNode = readNodeInfo(input);
            if (newNode != NULL) {
                add(&newNode, head);
            }
        }

        return *head;
    }

    void add(node_t** node, node_t** head){
        if (*head == NULL) {
            *head = *node;
            (*node)->next = NULL;
            return;
        }

        node_t* temp = *head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = *node;
        (*node)->next = NULL;
    }

    node_t* readNodeInfo(FILE* input){
        node_t* newNode = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
            if (newNode == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory allocation failed\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        fscanf(input, "%50[a-zA-Z], %50[a-zA-Z], %d, %d, %d, %10[a-zA- Z], %15[a-zA-Z]",
            newNode->lastName, newNode->firstName, &newNode>birthDay.month, &newNode->birthDay.day, 
            &newNode->birthDay.year, newNode->major, newNode->classStand);

        newNode->next = NULL;
        return newNode;
    }

    void printList(FILE* output, node_t* head){
            if (head == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "List is empty\n");
            return;
        }
        printBorder(output);

        fprintf(output, "LIST INFO:\n");
            node_t* current = head;
        while (current != NULL) {
            fprintf(output, "Name:\t%s %s\n", current->firstName, 
    current->lastName);
            fprintf(output, "Date of Birth:\t%d %d, %d\n", current- >birthDay.month, current->birthDay.day, current->birthDay.year);
            fprintf(output, "Major:\t%s\n", current->major);
            fprintf(output, "Year:\t%s\n\n", current->classStand);
    
            printBorder(output);

            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    void printBorder(FILE* output){
        for(int i = 0; i < 80; i++){
            fprintf(output, "*");
        }
        fprintf(output, "\n");
    }

    void deleteList(node_t** head){
        if (*head == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        node_t* current = *head;
        node_t* next;

        while (current != NULL) {
            next = current-> next;
            free(current);
            current = next;
        }

        *head = NULL;
    }
```

Heres the driver.c

```
#include "functions.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    assert(argc == 3 && "Incorrect number of command line 
arguments");

    FILE* input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    assert(input != NULL && "Error opening input file");

    FILE* output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    assert(output != NULL && "Error opening output file");

    node_t* head = NULL;
    head = createList(input, &head);

    printList(output, head);

    deleteList(&head);

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Heres the "fully" functioning test file:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct bDay {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    }date;

    typedef struct LinkList {
        date birthDay;

        char last[50];
        char first[50];
        char major[10];
        char class[15];

        struct Node *next;
    }Node;

    Node* createNode(FILE* input, FILE* output){
        Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        
        fscanf(input, "%50[a-zA-Z], %50[a-zA-Z], %d, %d, %d, %10[a-zA-Z], %15[a-zA-Z]", 
        newNode->last, newNode->first, &newNode->birthDay.month, &newNode->birthDay.day, &newNode->birthDay.year, 
        newNode->major, newNode->class);
        
        newNode->next = NULL;

        fprintf(output, "%s, %s, %d/%d/%d, %s, %s\n", newNode->first, newNode->last, newNode->birthDay.month, 
        newNode->birthDay.day, newNode->birthDay.year, newNode->major, newNode->class);

        return newNode;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        FILE* fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    Node* newNode = createNode(fp, fp2);
    
    

      // fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see the format string is the same. The difference seems to be that `newNode` points to different structs. Post the structs. That said, my guess is that the problem is something unrelated to the posted `fscanf`

Comment: A [mcve] and some sample input would be useful. You should be checking the return value from `fscanf` to see if it is converting the right number of items.

Comment: OT: Always check the return value from `fscanf`. And for debug it can help to print the value.

Comment: "...a second file with very similar code..." Do you want to share the file? Or shall we just guess

Comment: This is my first time using StackOverFlow, I'm getting there

Comment: @csm0104 That's okay. As long as you react to our comments and provide the additional information there is a chance that we can help.

Comment: It's not the root cause but it is a bug: When the char array is `[50]` you need `%49` to avoid overflow, i.e. one less than array size

Comment: okay, so you have posted the `struct` used in the `fscanf` that isn't working for you. We also need the `struct` definition for the `fscanf` that is working.

Comment: This seems like one of the classic `scanf` problems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer

Comment: "excluding the header file and the main function" Please explain to your rubber duck why you feel the need to exclude these bits.

Comment: Most of the posts I see are short snippets of code, I didnt wanna go and post like 300 lines of code

Comment: Learning many lessons

Comment: You also want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong

Comment: I've seen a few things about that, I'll try it out

Comment: So your file seems to be: "Doe,John,1,23,2000,CS-BS,Junior**newline**Bar,Foo,4,56,2000,CS-BS,Junior" After the first read the "file data" will be "**newline**Bar,Foo,4,56,2000,CS-BS,Junior". So what happens in the next read? What will the **<newline>** do?

Comment: I have't even gotten that far, I've spent the last like 3 hours trying to make it even read a single line. My brains fried right now, its been a long day

Comment: Last hint: Change your `fscanf` line so that you do: `int ret = fscanf(....` and then add `printf("Items scanned %d\n", ret);` If your code works you should see 7 all the time. My bet is that you see 7 the first time and then you'll see 0. Could that be due to the newline? ;-)

Comment: All files are posted now, I beyond clueless and beyond being a useful human being right now. Brain hurt. Ill try that int ret thing

Comment: @csm0104 okay one more hint: Add a space in the start of your format string, i.e. `" %49....`

Comment: OT: I'll recommend that you forget that you ever heard about `fscanf` (and `scanf`). Stop using them. Read from the file using `fgets` and then use `sscanf` for string parsing. Your (programming) live will get much easier.

Comment: Our teacher i belive has it in bold with at least one exclamation point that we have to use fscanf. We also have to use putty to ssh into the schools linux computers. I wanna die

Comment: Maybe your teacher wants you to learn how bad `fscanf` is... Hopefully, the teach ends the lesson by saying: "That's one of the many reasons that you should avoid `fscanf`"